# Selection sort time complexity for array type data structure in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, selection-sort

I have implemented selection sort using an array (not array list) in C#. the time complexity mentioned at most places for selection sort is O(n^2).

In my implementation below, I see it as O(n^3). Is there a way to make it O(n^2)?

In many books, which define time complexity of selection sort as O(n^2), I see the author doesn't consider the time complexity for pop or element removal step in array which is also O(n).

```
using System;
public class SortArray
{
 public int[] SlectionSort(int[] arr)
 {
   int[] newarr = new int[arr.Length];
   for(int i=0; i<newarr.Length; i++)
   {
     int smallest_index = findSmallest(arr);
     newarr[i] = arr[smallest_index];
     arr = pop(arr, smallest_index);
   }
   return newarr;
 }

 public int findSmallest(int[] arr)
 {
   int smallest = arr[0];
   int smallest_index = 0;

   for(int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
   {
     if(arr[i] < smallest)
     {
       smallest = arr[i];
       smallest_index = i;
     }
   }
   return smallest_index;
 }

 public static int[] pop(int[] arr, int index)
 {
   int size = arr.Length - 1; 
   int[] newArr = new int[size];
   int n = 0;
   for(int i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
   {
     if( i > newArr.Length-1)
     { 
     break;
     }
   if(i < index)
   {
      newArr[i] = arr[i];
   }
   else 
   {
     newArr[i] = arr[i+1];
   }
 }
 return newArr;
 }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please note that the code for questions must be provided as text inside the question itself. Links to code do not count as such links can disappear and there is generally no legal way (due to mismatches between licenses) for someone else to  get code edited into the question. So please [edit] the post to show code (consider reviewing [MCVE] guidance to make sure you include all necessary code)

Comment: Note that selection sort does not include any sort of stack or removal from an array - so it is very hard to see what you mean without code in the question - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  The code needs to be included *directly in the question*, and you must be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: I have added the code editing the post, i would like to know if this is the correct way to do selection sort using array in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that you're delaying the selection sort by forcing it to operate on fixed (rather than dynamic) memory.  When you see a general algorithm with a complexity listed, that's more of a guide than a promise.  If you don't match the data structures to the algorithm, you're not going to be able to achieve the same upper-bound time complexity.

> I see the author doesn't consider the time complexity for pop or element removal step in array which is also O(n).

Here's the sign that your input isn't organized right.  For a more extreme example, if I insisted on storing my list on a tape, array access is O(n), because I'd need to wait for the tape to spool under the read-head.  That doesn't mean that the algorithm is more complex; it means that the implementation is throwing roadblocks in the way of the algorithm.

In some cases that might be a necessary constraint.  But for the case in the question, you just want a data structure that doesn't take an algorithm to remove and insert items, like a `List`.